# Discussion Board - Missing Title

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, discussion-board, community-site

One of our Discussion Boards was configured to hide the Title field in the form (column was set to hidden in the Discussion Content Type).

As a result people could add an entry but it would show up as ***(no title)***.

I set the column back to "Required" again and the title can now be entered.
However for the existing entry I can see the title that was added after the item was created but when entering the thread it still shows up as ***(no title)***.

[image]

Question:
How does this happen ... which field is actually being used here?
Is there a way to make the 'new' titel show up within the thread as well?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: We updated the subject *after* setting the Subject/Title column of the Discussion Content Type to required. In the Flat view it is still being shown as (no title).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, **Title** column in Discussions List is displaying as **Subject**. You can go to Discussion content type in Discussions List settings and click "**Subject**" column, you will find that:
[image]

To make sure an existing **(no title)** item has title, you need to edit the item and type a title in **Subject** field.
[image]

Have a try and let's know the result.

## Updated:

The value in Flat view navigation is a folder name which by default is given the name of the discussion name when it is created. 
However, if you then change the discussion name, it does not automatically update the folder name. To change it, you can use SharePoint Designer 2013 to achieve it:

1. Open the site using SharePoint Designer 2013
2. Go to All files->lists->[your discussions list], then find the discussion that you want to change, and rename it:

[image]

## Updated on 12.6:

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow to change the folder's name when item is changed.

My demo workflow:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We already edited the Subject/Title field and set it to 'Required'. After that the user edited the Subject but it does not get displayed in the Flat view. I also updated the initial question.

Comment: The value is a folder name which by default is given the name of the discussion name when it is created. However, if you then change the discussion name, it does not automatically update the folder name. To change it, you can use SharePoint Designer 2013 to achieve it, I updated my answer to contains the detail steps.

Comment: I also updated my answer to contain a workflow to change the name, you can have a try.

Comment: Using the SPD worked. Did not use the workflow ins SPD since we generally use Nintex for things like that ;) But many thanks for the detailed reply/help!